# Non-Symmetric Real Matrix with eigen values $\in $ [0,1] but largest singular value > 1

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-norms, singular-values, contraction-operator

Matrix , M has all eigenvalues $\in$ [0,1], but on simulation, I can see that the largest singular value is >1.

a) Can anyone give an example of such a matrix in toy cases like 2x2

b) Can some property be pointed out that proves that even though eigenvalues $ \in  [0,1]$, but singular values $\notin [0,1]$ i.e. $\exists \sigma > 1$.

---

In symmetric case, we have $ \sigma_{max} = max\{| \lambda_{max}| ,| \lambda_{min}| \}$, thus we know that the largest singular value in this case would be 1.

Also, in non-symmetric case we know $\sigma_{max} =  \lambda_{max}(M^{T}M)^{\frac{1}{2}} $, so when we have $\lambda_{max}(M) >1$, we can get $ \sigma_{max}(M) > \lambda_{max}(M)$.

But how to find relation between $\lambda_{max} > \sigma_{max}$ in case $\lambda_{max}(M) = 1$

Comment: Question b and final sentence are unclear.

Comment: I can see no reason to focus on the value 1 in this context (think of what happens if you multiply M by a constant).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks , fixed exponent as $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @AnneBauval Reformulated part (b), does it makes sense now?

Comment: @AnneBauval Didn't get you in why to focus on eigen value = 1, I am focussing on $\lambda _{max}=1$,as when $\lambda_{max} = 1$ , I cant get convincing argument that $\sigma_{max} > \lambda_{max}$

Comment: Not more than for any value of $|\lambda_{max}|.$

Comment: The last sentence and the reformulation of part b) is are still a little strange but I think I can guess what you intend to as. Probably: when all eigenvalues are $\ge0,$ is there a known sufficient condition for $\sigma_{max}$ to be $>\lambda_{max}$?

Comment: @AnneBauval yes exactly.

Answer (score 2):

$\pmatrix{0&2\\ 0&0}$ gives a simple example. The largest singular value of a matrix is always bounded below by the spectral radius. When they are equal, the matrix is called *radial*. A complete characterisation of radial matrices is given by

> M. Goldberg and G. Zwas (1974), [On matrices having equal spectral radius and spectral norm](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379574900767), *Linear Algebra and Its Application*, 8: 427-434.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers on 'radial' matrix, but what I am specifically looking at is, that the largest eigen value of a non-symmetric matrix is 1, but largest singular values is > 1.

Comment: Thus, can you give pointers when largest eigen value = 1, but singular value is >1

Comment: Just change the $11$ entry of the above matrix to $1$ to get your example.

Comment: @poeplva This multiplication of M by 1/2 matches by comment about not focusing on 1.